# Access VBA: repeatedly change form filter with Me.Filter

Tags: ms-access, vba

Filters in Access seem to be 'sticky' - when you set one with VBA you can remove it but you can't set a different one.

I have a Access database for tracking student scores. It has tables `subjects`, `teachers`, `students`, `tests` and `test_results`. Each results record refers to a student and a test.

I have a form displaying tests with a subform displaying results. I want to search for tests using various criteria so I added some unbound fields to the (outer) form header and labelled them 'name', 'subject', 'start date', 'end date' and 'teacher'. I added a 'filter' button and a 'reset' button. Each search field is optional so any combination can be used: any left blank will be ignored.

This is the code for the filter button:

```vb
Me.Filter =
"([Forms]![testWithResults]![Text102] IS NULL OR test_name Like '*' & [Forms]![testWithResults]![Text102] & '*')
AND ([Forms]![testWithResults]![Combo89] IS NULL OR teacher = [Forms]![testWithResults]![Combo89])
AND ([Forms]![testWithResults]![Combo52] IS NULL OR subject = [Forms]![testWithResults]![Combo52])
AND ([Forms]![testWithResults]![Text83] IS NULL OR [Forms]![testWithResults]![Text85] IS NULL OR test_date BETWEEN [Forms]![testWithResults]![Text83] AND [Forms]![testWithResults]![Text85])"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

This is the code for the reset button:

```vb
Me.FilterOn = False
Me.Combo89 = Me.Combo89.DefaultValue
Me.Combo52 = Me.Combo52.DefaultValue
Me.Text83 = Me.Text83.DefaultValue
Me.Text85 = Me.Text85.DefaultValue
Me.Text102 = Me.Text102.DefaultValue
```

**When I first load the form, the first time I search it all works perfectly.** The filter button works just as expected and the reset button empties all fields and displays all records. **But when I try to search again with new criteria I just get my old results again.** To make it work I have to close and reopen the form.

When I replaced `Me.Filter` with `DoCmd.ApplyFilter` it still worked perfectly the first time but the second time I would get an error 'the expression is too complex to be evaluated'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Access complains the `Filter` string is too complex, simplify it.

You want to base a `Filter` condition on a text box.  At the time you create the `Filter` string, your code can check whether that text box is Null.  If it is not Null, add a condition based on the text box's value.  If it is Null, the `Filter` can simply ignore that text box.

```vb
Dim strFilter As String
With [Forms]![testWithResults]
    If Not IsNull(![Text102]) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND test_name Like '*" & ![Text102] & "*'"
    End If
    If Not IsNull(![Combo89]) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND teacher = " & ![Combo89]
    End If
    If Not IsNull(![Combo52]) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND subject = " & ![Combo52]
    End If
    If Not (IsNull(![Text83]) Or IsNull(![Text85])) Then
        strFilter = strFilter & " AND test_date BETWEEN " & Format(![Text83], "\#yyyy-m-d\#") _
            & " AND " & Format(![Text85], "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
    End If
End With
If Len(strFilter) > 0 Then
    ' use Mid() to discard leading " AND "
    Debug.Print Mid(strFilter, 6) '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
    Me.Filter = Mid(strFilter, 6)
    Me.FilterOn = True
Else
    MsgBox "no conditions for Filter"
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! It works but I didn't think it would... as searching a second time with Me.Filter didn't give me an error, it simply gave me my previous results: that's why I thought it was 'sticky'.